# Ember data relationship and fixtures

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

With ember data relationship can be `{async: true}` or `{async: false`}. How to create a model FIXTURES that mimic the behavior of an synced relashionship as described in the documentation :

```
var attr = DS.attr,
    hasMany = DS.hasMany,
    belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: attr(),
  comments: hasMany('comment'),
  user: belongsTo('user')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  body: attr()
});
```

Ember Data expects that a GET request to /posts/1 would return the JSON in the following format:

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Rails is omakase",
    "comments": ["1", "2"],
    "user" : "dhh"
  },

  "comments": [{
    "id": "1",
    "body": "Rails is unagi"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "body": "Omakase O_o"
  }]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to override the `find` method of the adapter. [Here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js#L137) is the current implementation of the `find` method in the `FixtureAdapter`. You can see that it simply finds the record with the given ID, then returns it. You're going to want to modify that so that it side-loads the proper records. Something like this:

```
var json = {};
json[type.typeKey] = requestedRecord;
type.eachRelationship(function(name, meta) {
    if (!meta.async) {
        json[meta.type.typeKey.pluralize()] = [ /* put related records here */ ];
    }
});
```

The syntax may not be perfect, but you should get the idea.